# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'comments' in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In a controller, I have an activequery with a sub select to get a count, and want to use the count to further limit by rows returned. e.g., comments = 0

I am using a having because that was the only way I could get this to work at the mysql prompt to test it.  Checking the aggregate function in the where clause does not work.

Any ideas?

And ultimately, my goal is to adjust this to a destroy statement to delete values that meet that criteria, but I don't even know how to do that.  So this means deleting rows from the hbookmarks table only ( not the bookmarks table ).

Code from controller:

```
Hbookmark.joins("INNER JOIN bookmarks ON hbookmarks.bookmark_id = bookmarks.id")
         .select("bookmarks.short_name, hbookmarks.id, ( select count(*) from clickcomments where clickcomments.click_id = hbookmarks.id ) as comments")
         .where("bookmarks.user_id = ? AND hbookmarks.create_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR )", current_user.id)
         .having("comments = 0")
         .order("hbookmarks.create_date desc")
```

Comment: Totally not cool, but raw sql worked.  But don't want to use it. Rather do active record.  `sql = "select b.short_name, h.create_date, h.id, ( select count(*) from clickcomments c where c.click_id = h.id ) as commentcount from bookmarks b, hbookmarks h where b.user_id=#{current_user.id} and h.bookmark_id = b.id and h.create_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)  having commentcount=0  order by h.create_date desc"
  @topurge = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

Comment: sorry, substituted commentcount for comments, to be more clear

Comment: Someone cleaned up by code, but there was a debugger line which I will explain was important. `logger.info("purge size with no comments: " + @topurge.size.to_s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately it was failing on the size command on the ActiveRecord, which I had in a logger statement.

```
logger.info("purge size with no comments: " + @topurge.size.to_s)
```

Using .length did not cause the error, and the rest of query worked fine.  I commented out the .length once done.

The correct way is:

```
logger.info("purge size with no comments: " + @topurge.length.to_s)
```

As to my other question, how to do a delete, that straight forward, destroy_all on the ActiveRecord.  Now my database had a few users with 1000s of rows, so in that case, I went into mysql and did surgical deletes that performed fast versus this activerecord is slow.  Is someone has a better, faster, less impact on performance way to do deletes inside Rails, please let me know.

```
# remove the old clicks that do not have comments - we'll keep those for search look up
@topurge.destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues before, I've solved it by replacing `comments` with the actual SQL segment you use to define it:

```
having("( select count(*) from clickcomments where clickcomments.click_id = hbookmarks.id ) = 0")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  When I do that, the hbookmarks.id is not known.`( select count(*) from clickcomments where clickcomments.click_id = hbookmarks.id )` causes Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'hw.hbookmarks.id' in 'where clause'